# How to write files to external public storage in Android so that they are visible from Windows?

Tags: java, android

My app should save files to a place where, when you connect your phone/tablet to a computer, you can see them through the system file explorer.

This is the way I implemented file writing:

```
protected String mDir = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS;
protected File mPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mDir);

protected void writeLogFile(String filename) {
    File f = new File(mPath, filename + ".txt");
    f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, false))) {

        // Details omitted.

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    makeText("Wrote " + f.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

This is what I see when I connect my Sony Xperia Z4 tablet to Windows (notice missing documents folder):

[image: windows file explorer showing tablet contents]

This is the directory to which the file is written (using above implementation):

[image: android device monitor showing file system]

What is wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> What is wrong with my implementation?

`MediaStore` has not discovered your newly-created files yet. What you see in Windows — and in many on-device "gallery" apps — is based on what `MediaStore` has indexed.

Use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to tell `MediaStore` about your file, once you have written out your data to disk:

```
public void scanFile(Context ctxt, File f, String mimeType) {
    MediaScannerConnection
        .scanFile(ctxt, new String[] {f.getAbsolutePath()},
                  new String[] {mimeType}, null);
}
```

or, in Kotlin:

```
fun scanFile(ctxt: Context, f: File, mimeType: String) {
  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ctxt, arrayOf(f.getAbsolutePath()), arrayOf(mimeType), null)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I really think they ought to include this information in the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). I take it that the MediaStore would eventually find these files on its own?

Comment: @transporter_room_3: Yes. There is a tiny edition of the Googlebot that scans external storage periodically, plus on reboots, to update the `MediaStore` roster of files. The file would eventually show up.