# I can't see image files when I connect my android phone to computer

Tags: android, image, file, storage

I'm developing android app using kitkat flatform device.

I saved images by using

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

When I connect my phone to computer(laptop), however, I can't see images. When I use the File-Manager App on the device, I can see those files.

How can I see images on my computers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: @CommonsWare I appreciate your help.  I solved my problem  thanks to  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(). and sorry about my ugly english writing