# File management system on Android 6 Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

`Environment.getExternalSourceDirectory` is not working for Android 6. Is the problem due to encryption which is introduced in Marshmallow? How could I access my files as a file manager?
My program goes like this:

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    File f;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String[] s;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        f=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        s=f.list();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}`

and my targeted sdk is as follows:
android:targetSdkVersion="18

Comment: "Environment.getExternalSourceDirectory not working for Android 6" -- I am not aware of any method ever existing in Android, named `getExternalSourceDirectory()`, on `Environment`. Do you mean [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory())?

Comment: Yes I am new to programming in Android so a bit of error in function name

Comment: Please explain what "is not working" means. Also, you might wish to review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl