# Can't access own app's files on computer

Tags: android, file-access

I have an app that writes files to the shared storage via `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. My problem is accessing and copying the files to a computer:

I can access these files from the computer if the phone has an SD card (tested on a Galaxy S5). However, I cannot access these files if the phone does not have an SD card (tested on a Nexus 5X). Strangely, I can view my app's files from the phone in **both** cases.

Am I using the wrong method to get the base directory? Or is it the phone? All I need is for the files to be copied from the phone to the computer. Any help is appreciated.

Note: Both running Android 6.0.1 if that helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: Thank you! Not sure how I missed that question before posting my own. The static method `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, path, null, null)` is what I went with.

Answer (score 2):

You can access to primary **shared/external** storage directory using **android's monitor**.

> You must open the monitor application while your app is running.

Open your android sdk folder then you will see a folder called **tools**, open it and search **monitor**, if you are in a mac you can open it /Users/YOUR-USER/Library/android-sdk-macosx/monitor.

After you opened the monitor application look for these folders data/data/yourAppPackage and there you will find **app_data**, **chache**, **databases**, **shared_prefs**.

Once you have opened monitor application

[image]

I hope that helps

Comment: Unfortunately this is not exactly what I wanted. I needed it to be available immediately after plugging in via the OS file explorer without Device Monitor. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: @ricefarmer369 I see, well why not try with this official software https://www.android.com/filetransfer/ ?