# Directory not being created publicly on Android device using File.mkdir()

Tags: android, directory, environment, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to create a directory on my Android device using the following code:

```
// If directory doesn't exist, create it.
File fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , "MyApp");
if (!fileDir.isDirectory()) {
    fileDir.mkdir();
}
```

I believe the directory is being created in `/storage/emulated/0/`. How can I create it to be publicly viewable in the internal storage?

For example, when the phone is connected to my PC, it should be in `Phone/MyApp`. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/` is the "root" directory show on your PC. But inside Android (as it is a Linux file system) that's the location.