# Import a video from the gallery then save it in another folder

Tags: android

The concept behind my application may not make sense, but I just need it to demonstrate something.
What I want to do is:

1 - import a video from android gallery
2 - rename it (xyz for example)
3 - save it under different folder (ABC)

The complete path will be, for example:

```
 "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ABC/XYZ.mp4"
```

I managed to call the intent to display the gallery where I will pick the intended video, but I don't know what should I write in the onActivityResult?

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Video"),TAKE_Video);
        }
    }
```

I added this code following @CommonsWare steps but nothing happens :(

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_Video) {

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Pictures/Targets/"); ///storage/emulated/0/Directory Name
            if (!root.exists()) {
                root.mkdirs();
            }
            try {

                FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());

                File file;
                String newname="newname.mp4";
                file = new File(root,newname);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, len);

                }

                fos.flush();
                fos.getFD().sync();
                fos.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I managed to call the intent to display the gallery where I will pick the intended video" -- please edit your question and provide a [mcve], demonstrating what you are doing for this, as that will help steer recommendations for how to use the result.

Comment: Sorry about that, I add the intent code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: In `onActivityResult()`, check the request code (1st parameter) to see if it is `RESULT_LOAD_Video`, and check the result code (2nd parameter) to see if it is `RESULT_OK`.

Step #2: When both checks from step #1 are true, create a `FileOutputStream` on your desired destination file, with the new name.

Step #3: Call `getContentResolver().openInputStream()`, passing in the value of `getData()` called on the `Intent` passed into `onActivityResult()` (3rd parameter).

Step #4: Use Java I/O to read bytes from the `InputStream` you got in step #3 and write them to the `FileOutputStream` that you got in step #2.

Step #5: When you are done copying the bytes, call `flush()`, `getFD().sync()`, and `close()`, respectively, on the `FileOutputStream`.

Step #6: When you have all of that working, move the code for steps #2-5 to a background thread, as you should not do this sort of I/O on the main application thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I'm struggling with the fourth step how is it done exactly? Sorry I'm a newbie at this

Comment: I added the code following the steps you mentioned but nothing happens..can you please check what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @NuhaAbd: You are calling `startActivityForResult()` and passing in `RESULT_LOAD_Video`. You are checking for `TAKE_Video` in `onActivityResult()`. These are not the same symbols and perhaps do not resolve to the same `int` values.

Comment: Sorry my bad I didn't edite the previous   posted code. I've changed it to Take video but nothing happens

Comment: @NuhaAbd: I am not sure how you are determining whether something happens or not. For example, if you are looking for the file via a desktop OS, [you have more work to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl). Beyond that, use a debugger or logging statements to see what is and is not getting executed.

Comment: I'm connecting my device (Samsung Note 4 ) to it and run the application on it. The application runs and I can select the video but that it. What I'm expecting is to see the video selected  in the new specified folder. so I check the gallery folder but nothing is there

Comment: @NuhaAbd: "so I check the gallery folder but nothing is there " -- I do not know what a "gallery folder" is. If you mean something inside of a gallery-style application, usually those apps use `MediaStore`, not the filesystem, and you have not done anything to update the `MediaStore` index. Your video will show up eventually (e.g., tomorrow). If you want it to show up faster, [you have more work to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl).

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you ! I rebooted the mobile and taa daa all the folders and files are there!.