# Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory returns bad value

Tags: android, database

```
public void exportDatabse(String databaseName) {

        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
           if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+databaseName+"";
                String backupDBPath ="//database.sql";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();

                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                    Log.i(TAG,"coping database sucessfull");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG,"exception! "+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

While debugging the `sd` file location `File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` is

> /storage/emulated/0

[image]

The copied file isn't visible in my SDcard. Moreover, I know the location of the `sd` file is incorrect. How can I get the database.sql file?
UPDATE

[image]

Comment: [External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). You have a lot of duplicated `/` values that should be fixed. And your copy will not be visible to most apps (and desktop operating systems), unless [you get that copy indexed by the `MediaStore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl).

Answer (score 2):

The value returned by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` is correct and there is nothing wrong with it.

The problem here is that the *Android Device Monitor* doesn't directly support symlinks (symbolic links). You should manually follow/expand them in the File Explorer.

So in your case you need to expand the `storage` folder followed by the `emulated` and `0` folder.

If that doesn't work you might want to try to expand the `storage` folder followed by the `self` and `primary` folder.

**TLDR:** manually follow/expand the paths in the `info` column.

**Edit:**
Try expanding the folders marked in yellow.

[image: Android Device Monitor File Explorer]

Comment: the files on my destination folders are in folder 6314-6720 so i need to create file on that path? did you have any expirience how to do it?

Comment: You don't need to create anything (your code seems fine), just expand the correct folders and follow the symlinks. Also make sure you code doesn't fail (check the logcat), you also need permission to write to the external storage: WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: in Android Device Monitor? The storage/emulate folder is empty or i dont have acces to it

Comment: I expand it and my 6314-6720 are contatin my sd card and self contatin empty primary folder (screens in question) but both doesnt contatin database.sql file

Comment: Check if your code successfully executes (no exceptions are thrown). I also would like to mention @CommonsWare, his comment contains some good information.

Comment: Code does not throw any exception, I checked the @CommonsWare, thanks