# Can't save image to storage - Android

Tags: java, android

```
package ar.camera;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import static android.provider.MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Uri fileUri;

    //create the file URI
    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }


    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type){

        final File mediaStorageDir;

        if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "EMFDetectingApp");
        } else{
            mediaStorageDir = new File ("/storage/sdcard0/EMFDetectingApp");
        }

        if(  !mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("EMFDectectingApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        //create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile = null;
        if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
            return mediaFile;
        } else{
            return null;
        }



    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

        //create the uri of a file to save the image
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        //specifying the path and file name for teh received image
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                //image cpatured and saved to fileUri specifies in the Intent
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image capture cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image capture failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }


}
```

I've created an app which uses the camera to take and image then save it. However when I run the above code, I can take a picture but the image does not get saved. I cant find it in gallery or SD card. Can anyone find the mistake in this code?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone find the mistake in this code?

- You are calling `startActivityForResult()` before you are done setting up the `Intent` — call `putExtra()` **before** calling `startActivityForResult()`
- **Never hardcode paths** (e.g., `/storage/sdcard0/EMFDetectingApp`), as such paths may not exist on all devices.
- You cannot write to `/storage/sdcard0/` on Android 4.4+ devices, if that is [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).
- You cannot use `Uri.fromFile()` on Android 7.0+ devices, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 or higher
- Your photo will not be visible to Windows/macOS/Linux, or to most gallery apps, until you [have `MediaScannerConnection` index the photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl).

Comment: when i call putExtra before calling startActivityForResult, my app wont open it says "Camera keeps stopping"

Comment: also what is the alternative to Uri.fromFile() for android 7.0

Comment: @Programmer: "my app wont open it says "Camera keeps stopping"" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace from the other app. " what is the alternative to Ur.fromFile() for android 7.0" -- `FileProvider`. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) implements `FileProvider` for use with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.