# photos not available after capturing and saving

Tags: android

I have written this code (given below) to capture photos on button click. The problem is that when I capture photos (click on button) there is no photo available/saved in specified directory (pictures folder). I am not getting any error or exception. Please tell what is issue in my code?

**On Click Code:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    PhotoCapture.takeSnapShots(this, Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
    PhotoCapture.takeSnapShots(this, Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
}
```

**Photo Capturing and Saving Code:**

```
package com.example.appdeveloper.appname;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;


public class PhotoCapture {

    static Camera camera = null;
    static int pic_number = 0;

    public static void takeSnapShots(Context context, int face) {

        SurfaceView surface = new SurfaceView(context);
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        int cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == face) {
                try {
                    camera = Camera.open(camIdx);
                    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surface.getHolder());
                    camera.startPreview();
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.release();
                    camera = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ File.separator+"picure"+(++pic_number)+".jpg";
            File pictureFile = new File(path);

            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                Bitmap realImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                mtx.setRotate(90);
                realImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(realImage, 0, 0, realImage.getWidth(), realImage.getHeight(), mtx, true);
                realImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                camera.stopPreview();
                camera.release();
                camera = null;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: @CommonsWare please go through my question and given code.

Comment: Is onPictureTaken called?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }`. You are not informing the user if there is an exception.

Comment: `camera.stopPreview();`. You stop the preview before the user can take a picture.