# Android studio internal file path, file not saved

Tags: android, pdf, path

Small problem, I am trying to save my PDF file in phone (LG G5 - no SD card), but file is never saved, is there a problem with file path? Using PdfBox-Android library. See picture from debugger - [Debugger picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOCWX.png). The aim is to save pdf file to internal downloads folder. I tried 10x solutions, nothing is working. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The aim is to save pdf file to internal downloads folder

Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`, not `getFilesDir()`. Also:

- You will need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission
- You will need to handle [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
- You will need to [get the file indexed by the `MediaStore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl) before it will show up

Comment: Great, added runtime persmission and it works :) Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run the code on M version. Please check for Write External Storage permission and other read and write permissions in manifest file. For Android M and above versions use the concept of runtime permissions.

Let, me know if it was helpful.