# App files not visible in file explorer

Tags: android

I am creating a file and writing it like this:

```
                outputStream = context.openFileOutput(symbol, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                outputStream.write(DATA.getBytes());
                outputStream.close();
```

I can read the file from the app but I can't see the files in explorer. I need to make it visible in explorer so that it can be shared(for debugging). Also, I need the file to be in readable format (like txt) for the computer. Also, files needs to be stored in internal directory. How can I do it?

Comment: `openFileOutput` I suggest you read the documentation for that method.

Comment: What is "explorer"? Do you mean a file manager for a desktop OS?

Comment: @CommonsWare The file explorer of android.

Comment: @njzk2  I know it says there private file but check here it says other app can read it.https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html  . If you any other way then tell me.

Comment: @Lcukerd no it doesn't. `Context::openFileOutput` uses *Internal storage*, which according to the documentation : "Internal storage: [...] Files saved here are accessible by only your app.". You probably want to use external storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have your file be visible to other applications ("The file explorer of android"):

Step #1: Write to what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), such as `getExternalFilesDir()`

Step #2: Arrange to have [the file indexed by the `MediaStore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl), in case your file manager is using the `MediaStore` instead of the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to create a folder in external storage public directory.

Write this in manifest

```
<manifest>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Then you have to define a public folder in the external storage as follows :

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
         File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
    }
```

Here you can use DIRECTORY_PICTURES or any thing like DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS or any thing as you wish. 
You can even place your own public directory instead of DIRECTORY_PICUTRES.The use of this DIRECTORY_PICTURES is that all your files saved in this folder will be read as pictures by the system.

So be careful while working with these

Comment: I get file not found error. open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: From where are you trying to open the file ?

Comment: Well I am writing from WakefulBroadcastReceiver , and I am getting the error while writing using your code

Comment: I don't have idea about WakefulBroadcastReciever you can refer this for detailed explanation on how storage works :  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Well, it worked with Pictures directory but not documents. I dunno why /