# Can't see database file in external storage using file explorers

Tags: android, file, android-sqlite

I wanted to create database in external storage, so it can easily be modified from app and computer. There is no problem when I add or read from database using application, but there is nothing when I use file explorer on computer or phone. Moreover, the package directory, which should be in Android/data also doesn't exist.

Here is how database is created

```
public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DatabaseManager(final Context context, String databaseName) {
    super(new DatabaseContext(context), databaseName, null, VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_WAYPOINTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + WAYPOINTS_TABLE + "("
            + KEY_ID                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_NAME              + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_CHARACTERISTIC    + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + KEY_UKC               + " FLOAT,"
            + KEY_LONGITUDE         + " DOUBLE,"
            + KEY_LATITUDE          + " DOUBLE"
            + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_WAYPOINTS_TABLE);
}
```

And DatabaseContext, which is supposed to change database location:

```
public class DatabaseContext extends ContextWrapper {

private static final String DEBUG_CONTEXT = "DatabaseContext";
public DatabaseContext(Context base) {
    super(base);
}

@Override
public File getDatabasePath(String name) {
    String dbFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + "Android/data"
            + File.separator + getPackageName()
            + File.separator + name;

    if (!dbFile.endsWith(".db")) {
        dbFile += ".db" ;
    }

    File result = new File(dbFile);
    if (!result.getParentFile().exists()) {
        result.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }

    if (Log.isLoggable(DEBUG_CONTEXT, Log.WARN)) {
        Log.w(DEBUG_CONTEXT, "getDatabasePath(" + name + ") = " + result.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)    {
    SQLiteDatabase result = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(getDatabasePath(name), null);

    if (Log.isLoggable(DEBUG_CONTEXT, Log.WARN)){
        Log.w(DEBUG_CONTEXT, "openOrCreateDatabase(" + name + ",,) = " + result.getPath());
    }

    return result;
}
```

When I printed DatabaseContext.getDatabasePath(databaseName) result I got

> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.bearcave.passageplanning/database.db

as expected

The question is what am I doing wrong, that database and package directory are not created in external storage directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I didn' help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that since Android level 11 new open `openOrCreateDatabase` method was added and I haven't overrode it. When I added:

```
@Override
public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase(String name, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    return openOrCreateDatabase(name, mode, factory);
}
```

`DatabaseContext` started to work properly and database has been created in external storage.