# Create folder inside android folder of android device

Tags: android, local-storage, directory

We all know there is always a folder in android named **Android** which always contains data of app.
I saw many app folder inside it which store their file there.
So my question is **how can i create a folder inside android folder of an android device and store my application data inside of it?**

Please suggest something

Answer (score 0):

> We all know there is always a folder in android named Android which always contains data of app

I am assuming that you are referring to the `Android/` directory seen in what the Android SDK refers to as [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

> how can i create a folder inside android folder of an android device and store my application data inside of it?

Use `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, or `getExternalMediaDir()`, all methods available on implementations of `Context`, such as `Activity` and `Service`.

Also, if you want to be able to see the files that you create from  your desktop OS, you will need to arrange to [have the files indexed by the `MediaStore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl).