# i cannot find my written files

Tags: javascript, java, android

I wrote a file to the sd card (external storage) of my phone. I cannot see these files in the created folder for these files, but i can use them in the app. 
Here is proof i write to my sd card:

```
if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
        b3.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), file_namea);
    }
```

then i later on declare the file:

```
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
 ObjectOutputStream of = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
```

This works as the folder i created and i can use the file in the app but why can i not see or touch it when looking on my sd card?I would like to be able to email/ move the text files to my main pc but i cannot. 
Any ideas of how i can do so?

```
private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
File myExternalFile;
String myData = "";
```

> 09-01 13:58:04.255 1579-5528/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER from system 4389:com.motorola.process.system/1000 pkg com.motorola.motgeofencesvc
>                                                     java.lang.Throwable
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18226)
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18826)
>                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:512)
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2906)
>                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
>   09-01 13:58:04.319 1579-5293/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER from system 4389:com.motorola.process.system/1000 pkg com.motorola.motgeofencesvc
>                                                     java.lang.Throwable
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18226)
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18826)
>                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:512)
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2906)
>                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
>   09-01 13:58:07.239 579-690/? E/ThermalEngine: override_notify: SS mode 0 override
>   09-01 13:58:08.791 5148-5153/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
>   09-01 13:58:17.529 4412-4412/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: ICC ID is null or empty.
>   09-01 13:58:24.424 5148-5153/? E/ANDR-PERF-MPCTL: Invalid profile no. 0, total profiles 0 only
>   09-01 13:58:24.425 579-690/? E/ThermalEngine: override_notify: SS mode 1 override
>   09-01 13:58:24.451 1579-6929/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER from system 4389:com.motorola.process.system/1000 pkg com.motorola.motgeofencesvc
>                                                     java.lang.Throwable
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18226)
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18826)
>                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:512)
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2906)
>                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
>   09-01 13:58:24.480 1579-4775/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER from system 4389:com.motorola.process.system/1000 pkg com.motorola.motgeofencesvc
>                                                     java.lang.Throwable
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18226)
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18826)
>                                                         at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:512)
>                                                         at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2906)
>                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
>   09-01 13:58:27.426 579-690/? E/ThermalEngine: override_notify: SS mode 0 override
>   09-01 13:58:29.139 1579-5454/? E/LocSvc_libulp: E/int ulp_brain_transition_all_providers(), no QUIPC/GNSS transition logic run due to both engines are OFF 
>   09-01 13:58:30.336 1579-4147/? E/MotoSensors: rearprox readEvents
>   09-01 13:58:30.336 1579-4147/? E/MotoSensors: RearProxSensor: unknown event (type=3, code=25,value=1)
>   09-01 13:58:30.336 1579-4147/? E/MotoSensors: RearProxSensor: unknown event (type=3, code=16,value=1504270710)
>   09-01 13:58:30.336 1579-4147/? E/MotoSensors: RearProxSensor: unknown event (type=3, code=17,value=336310)
>   09-01 13:58:30.336 1579-4147/? E/MotoSensors: RearProxSensor: unknown event (type=3, code=18,value=18)
>   09-01 13:58:30.336 1579-4147/? E/MotoSensors: RearProxSensor: unknown event (type=3, code=20,value=822272)
>   09-01 13:58:30.336 1579-4147/? E/MotoSensors: RearProxSensor: unknown event (type=3, code=21,value=5120)
>   09-01 13:58:30.336 1579-4147/? E/MotoSensors: RearProxSensor: unknown event (type=3, code=22,value=333519)
>   09-01 13:58:47.702 4412-4412/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] getIccId: ICC ID is null or empty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: What need for _javascript_ tag ?

Comment: How is your js/java mixed?

Comment: Can you log the actual value of `getExternalFilesDir(filepath)`. On some devices the internal storage is available as simulated external storage, so your files might have ended up in the internal memory.

Comment: And can you write in it, then read its contents from it?

Comment: "why can i not see or touch it when looking on my sd card?" - please clarify what you mean by "looking on my sd card".

Comment: @DodgyCodeException when i go through the phones folders outside of the app

Comment: @Lothar added it in

Comment: Please tell the value of myExternalFile.getAbsolutePath(). All has nothing to do with a removable microSD card. So you do not have to look on it. This is what @Lothar asked.

Comment: `when i go through the phones folders outside of the app` Still unclear what you are doing. How?

Comment: `private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";` That is not a file path. So don't name that variable like that. Confusing code!

Comment: @greenapps apps it has created that folder on my sd card

Comment: @greenapps when i connect my phone and go through the computer section with shows me the internal storage and my sd card

Comment: @greenapps myExternalFile.getAbsolutePath(). how can i tag this in logcat?

Comment: @greenapps i want to impliment this into my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: Log.d("used path",  myExternalFile.getAbsolutePath());

Comment: `when i connect my phone` to what?

Comment: @greenapps my pc

Comment: As you do not have to look at the sd card you should look elsewhere. Now tell us value of getAbsolutePath().

Comment: But of course you should use a File Explorer app on your device. Even if you look at the right path from your computer you will not see the file at once.

Comment: @greenapps i put the log cat there

Comment: Why? What should we see? Can you read that mess? Remove it. Post only relevant lines. And put them in a code block so they are readable.

Comment: If you cannot find that Log.d() statement in your logs than you could show a Toast() too of course.