# Unable to pick audio file from storage

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, android-mediarecorder

I am recording audio using `MediaRecorder` in Android, it saves the file in `3gp` format. Everything works perfect, audio is recorded and it can be played using media player but when I want to pick this file from storage using `Intent` I am unable to select this file.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(intent, AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Did you arrange to have the file be indexed by the `MediaStore`?

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: Great!! Works fine . Thank you :)