# Can't find screen recorded video (/sdcard/capture.mp4") - Mediaprojection API

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaprojection, mediaprojectionmanager

I'm still a biginner on android APP development and I'm trying to use Mediaprojection API to record my screen .. the issue that I am facing now is.. After recording I cant find the video file in the defined location (sdcard/capture.mp4) .. below is the part of the code that show the location of where I want to save my video ...

```
private void initRecorder() {
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/capture.mp4");
}
```

Thank you very much for your support .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem above by defining my path as shown on the line below ...
I set the download folder as my destination and now  I can see the recorded video 
NOTE: with this solution the new video will overwrite the previous one.

Hope this will also help someone in future ..

Thanks to nope4561759 for the contribution...

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/video.mp4");
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is probably **"/sdcard/"**. It is generally best practice to use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead of "/sdcard/", as not all Android devices use that as their external storage directory (I haven't seen that on any Android device for a while now, actually). On my Pixel running Android 8.1.0, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` returns an absolute path of **"/storage/emulated/0"**.

So instead of:

`mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/capture.mp4");`

Try this:

```
String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(dir + "/capture.mp4");
```

Comment: hello nope4561759 .. Thanks for your support .. I tried the method above but still I cant find the video ... there is no any error from the code also I tried to check the Logcat it shows no error .. but from the warning I could get this two line .... 02-27 10:10:45.337 28185-28185/com.confusedbox.screenrecorder W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.confusedbox.screenrecorder-2/lib/arm64
02-27 10:10:46.214 28185-28243/com.confusedbox.screenrecorder W/linker: /vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a

Comment: and from Info .. I could get these lines ....02-27 10:10:45.255 28185-28185/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-27 10:10:45.256 28185-28185/? I/art: Reinit property: dalvik.vm.checkjni= false

02-27 10:10:46.023 28185-28185/com.confusedbox.screenrecorder I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustActivityImpl
02-27 10:10:46.038 28185-28185/com.confusedbox.screenrecorder I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl

Comment: The program that I am using I downloaded from this link ..https://github.com/chinmoyp/screenrecorder   Thank you very much for your support

Comment: Have you set the proper write permission in the manifest? See the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage) on writing to external storage.