# save bitmap to SDcard not creating any file

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-bitmap

I want to save a bitmap as jpg file to my SDcard when a button is pressed. When I run the following code i get no error, but when I check the SDcard on the phone, no file is created. What am I doing wrong ?

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            }

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            //String root = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
            File myDir = new File(root + "/Screenshots");
            myDir.mkdirs();
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = generator.nextInt(10000);
            String fname = n+".jpg";
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);
            Log.d("DD",""+file);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                rBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I have the permission in the manifest, but still no file is generated:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I have done some research that suggest getExternalStorageDirectory() does not give the path to SDcard, but the following alternative gives null:

String root = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");

Comment: Why you are deleting a file and saving bitmap.

Comment: Use `if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }`

Comment: Just deleting existing file if the same filename exists.

Comment: There should be a file, if you want to edit it. If you delete an existing file, There is no file in that path so you can't edit it. Try using the above code

Comment: just tried it but still not seeing any file: try {file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    rBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);out.flush();out.close();} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: no exception at all. This is in my log if i keep pressing the button: 
D/DD: /storage/emulated/0/Screenshots/149.jpg
I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=245KB, data=163KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=165KB, data=102KB
D/DD: /storage/emulated/0/Screenshots/5271.jpg
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=228KB, data=179KB After code cache collection, code=228KB, data=179KB Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
D/DD: /storage/emulated/0/Screenshots/2345.jpg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: Thanks but still don't see any file. I added the following after out.close(): MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(activity, new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()},new String[] {null}, null); activity.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE));

Comment: You are not saving to an SD card but to Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().. You should look at the right place first. Please post logs in a normal way in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: `myDir.mkdirs();` Do not call mkdirs() blindly. Replace by `if ( !myDir.exists()) if ( !myDir.mkdirs(){Toast ( ... could not create directory ...); return;}`

Comment: `if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }` That is not needed. You also dont have to create a new file (as suggested here) as the new FileOutputStream will delete and create the file.

Comment: `Thanks but still don't see any file. ` It looks if you are abusing the Gallery app to see if your file is there. Wrong! You should instead use a file explorer app on your device and look in the right folder/path. Is the directory created?

Comment: `have the permission in the manifest` Ok. But that is not enough for Android 6+ as you can read every day here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer as pointed out by @CommonsWare that's to call MediaScannerConnection.scanFile, so MediaStore can discover the file and list them in file explorer. Also suggested by @greenapps the files are in the external storage 0, not in the SDcard.

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            }

            String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("").toString();
            //String root = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
            File myDir = new File(root + "/Screenshots");
            if (!myDir.exists())
                if (!myDir.mkdirs())
                    {Toast.makeText(activity, "make dir failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); return;}
            Random generator = new Random();
            int n = generator.nextInt(10000);
            String fname = n+".jpg";
            File file = new File(myDir, fname);
            Log.d("DD",""+file);
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                rBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //add mediastore discovery
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(activity, new String[] {file.getAbsolutePath()},new String[] {null}, null);
        }
    }
```