# not able to add a directory to my DCIM folder

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-file

I've been looking around google and stack overflow for answers to this question. Why can't I create a folder in the DCIM directory with the correct permissions in my android manifest file... Here's the code, hopefully someone can help me.

```
    final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM) + File.separator + "mycustomdirectory");

    if (!f.exists()) {
        Log.d("folder", "Folder doesn't exist, creating it...");
        boolean rv = f.mkdir();
        Log.d("folder", "Folder creation " + ( rv ? "success" : "failed"));
    } else {
        Log.d("folder", "Folder already exists.");
    }
```

Found this code on stackoverflow....

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Folder creation failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it, then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: nope nothing i saw in those posts helped.

Comment: "with the correct permissions in my android manifest file" - is `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` actually granted? Check the app permissions in settings - make sure its toggled on.

Comment: ok - so the permission is toggeld off, but then i do this http://p.ip.fi/cQN- and i dont get a popup asking for permission within my app?

Answer (score 0):

after android 6.0, you need to check or request permissions dynamically. use the following code to check if need permission

```
private boolean needPermission() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            ApplicationUtils.getAppContext(), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERM) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

and use the following code to request permission

```
public void requestPermission() {
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        showDialog(R.string.title_permission, R.string.rational_permission_writing_external_storage,
                android.R.string.ok, android.R.string.cancel, false,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.i("TAG", "should try to request the permission");
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERM},
                                REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                    }
                }, null);
    } else {
        Log.i("TAG", "should try to request the permission");
        requestPermissions(new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERM},
                REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure what WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERM
                REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has as values in your code could you share? i just tried this and it didnt work http://p.ip.fi/cQN-

Comment: it's static variable in Manifest: Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: still not working... no dialog is being presented asking for permissions.