# File is not created in SDCARD

Tags: android, io

I am using this method, found in a lot of questions here in SO:

```
public void generateNoteOnSD(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
    try {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"folder", "AGL");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        if(gpxfile.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "KO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Almacen.setRutaFichero(gpxfile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have this in my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Everything seems to be ok, no exception is thrown, the right Toast is shown in screen...but I go to the folder where the file should be...and its not there. And I am scratching my head, because this very method worked ok a couple of times! I am using a library that writes logs and all...and the files with the logs are there...

Any help?

Comment: Creating a file on the SD Card requires the access permission of the `DocumentTree`

Comment: Can you elaborate...?

Comment: Have given runtime permission for write storage ?

Comment: I am using a API 16 device, and will not run in another device, so no need of that

Comment: If you run on APi 23+ then you need `DocumentTree` permission otherwise known as SAF more info [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider)

Comment: Have you debugged that code, from which line its stop executing?

Comment: It is not stopping executing anywhere, it just simply does not create the file...

Comment: what filename are you passing?

Comment: I am calling it "peticion".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: I guess you are finding a file anywhere else.

Comment: Did you solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If the "OK" toast displays, the file has already been created successfully. So why can not see the file?

1. check `Almacen.setRutaFichero(gpxfile.getAbsolutePath());`  what does the method do?
2. go to correct file location, in your case it will be:

[image]

3. manually refresh the folder using mouse