# Downloaded file not visible from the file browser

Tags: java, android

I download a file from firebase using file like. If I run this code on android emulator then I can see the downloaded file from file browser but in the real phone, it does not display the file.

```
private void DownloadFromStorage(String fileName) {
    // CREATE FOLDER IF NOT EXIST
    File dir = new File(DownloadActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(null), "notes");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        boolean b = dir.mkdir();
    }
    // CREATE FILE 
    File file = new File(DownloadActivity.this.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
    
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("note")
            .child(fileName);
    Log.d("downloadFile: " ,""+ storageReference.getPath());
    
    storageReference.getFile(file).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            if (getBaseContext() != null) {
                txtStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myToast("Download Complete.");
                Log.d("downloadFile: " ,"DOWNLOAD COMPLETE");
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            if (getBaseContext() != null) {
                txtStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                myToast("Download Fail");
                Log.d("downloadFile: " ,"DOWNLOAD FAIL");
            }
        }
    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(@NonNull FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String uc = String.format("Downloading... %.2f ", progress);
            if (getBaseContext() != null) txtStatus.setText(uc);
        }
    });
}
```

**How can I see this file from the file browser?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: `boolean b = dir.mkdir();` If b==false you should stop/return. Not continue as you do now.

Comment: @  blackapps after boolean b = dir.mkdir() there is more code but here those are not applicable for this question so I remove them.

Comment: @CommonsWare presently this code not working